# How can I create code that loops to change the location of text on screen

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a loop that will display a message, then it will increase the X or Y position of the text and display it again. I have attempted this below but it does not work: (please bare in mind that I have other code in the application but in the code bellow I want the string "helo" to be written on the screen several times from the left to the right of the command window. all the code does at the moment is flash in the same spot)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Menu();
    }

    static void Menu()
    {
        while(true)
      {
       PrintToScreendynamic(1, 1, "helo");
      {
    }

    static void PrintToScreendynamic(int x, int y, string text)
    {
        y++;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `y` to a static field in the `Program` class, remove it from the method declaration (and the call), and what you have will work.

Comment: Have you tried changing what values you pass as the x and y parameters? Because currently your code prints at 1,2 every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int parameter for your method is passed as a **value-type**, which means that the variable holding the values for x and y on your method **PrintToScreendynamic** have a local value scope of only that method. So the next time you call the method, those values are lost because you resend 1 and 1. What you need is to move the increment call to the outside method, so it does get sets and stored on memory and then send it to the internal method you created.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Menu();
    }

    static void Menu()
    {
      int x = 1;
      int y = 1;
      while(true)
      {
         PrintToScreendynamic(x, y, "helo");
         y++;
      }
    }

    static void PrintToScreendynamic(int x, int y, string text)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(text);
    }
}
```

You might want to sleep the process between each cycle to make the effect a bit more visible.

For a better understanding about value-type parameters:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t0za5es.aspx